# Oracle Block Statement DBMS output syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, syntax

I made this account just for this question because I'm really not sure how to word it properly for google to pick up on it. So here goes...

I was working on a query for a group project that I was assigned in my database II course. I made 2 and was working on a third when I wanted to see if I could do something like the following.

```
declare
Emp_ID := 03;
Salary_Increment := 2.0 --constants do not change
Salary_ID := 03;
Current_Salary := 47500
Updated_Salary := Current_Salary * 2.0
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('The Employee with the ID of' +Emp_ID 'will receive a 2% bonus.');
dbms_output.put_line('This Employees new salary will be: ' +Updated_Salary ');
end;
```

I attempted to do this previously but with a more simple code snippet. Figured I would see if I could do this just to simplify how much I have to type out.

TL;DR - Can I use a reference like    +Emp_ID     in a Oracle SQL dbms output?

Comment: The [concatenation operator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm) is `||`. I’m not clear what this has to do with `dbms_output` specifically though, or with PL/SQL in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In oracle, There are two ways of concating the string.

- using `||` operator.

Like this.

```
dbms_output.put_line('The Employee with the ID of' || Emp_ID || ' will receive a 2% bonus.');
```

- using `CONCAT` method.

Like this:

```
dbms_output.put_line(CONCAT(CONCAT('The Employee with the ID of', Emp_ID), ' will receive a 2% bonus.'));
```

Note that `CONCAT` uses only two parameter as input. So you need to use it multiple times to concat more than 2 strings.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

The string concatenation operator is `||` in PL/SQL, so you'd want to write

```
dbms_output.put_line('The Employee with the ID of' || Emp_ID || ' will receive a 2% bonus.');
```